# How does Dafny implement datatypes in C# and their hierarchy?

Tags: c#, hierarchy, implementation, dafny

I implemented one .Net Web Application that uses a .dll library verified completely in Dafny. It works well and the communication with the library is not difficult. It is wonderful.

Unfortunately, some parts of the code don't seem nice and I would like to ask whether I didn't use the library well or it's the correct way to use it. I speak about datatypes. I included a simple example in order to ask questions.

```
module DafnyCalculation
{
    datatype Calculation = Sum(s1:int, s2:int) | Rest(r1:int, r2:int) 
                        | Mult(m1:int, m2:int) | Div (d1:int, d2:int)

    function method calculate(cal:Calculation): int
    {
        match cal
            case Sum(s1,s2) => s1+s2
            case Rest(r1,r2) => r1-r2
            case Mult(m1,m2) => m1*m2
            case Div(d1,d2) => 
                if(d2!=0) then d1/d2 
                else d1
    }
}
```

As the datatype has more than one constructor, when .dll is generated dafny creates some classes automatically: Calculation, Base_Calculation, Calculation_Sum, Calculation_Rest, Calculation_Mult and Calculation_Div with the different parameters. I use the dll in the following way in a C# console application:

```
int result;
Base_Calculation cal;
Console.WriteLine("Enter first number: "); int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter second number: "); int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Choose operator:\n1)Sum\n2)Rest\n3)Mult\n4)Div\nOperator: "); 
int op = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
switch (op)
{
    case 1:
        cal = new Calculation_Sum((BigInteger)x, (BigInteger)y);
        break;
    case 2:
        cal = new Calculation_Rest((BigInteger)x, (BigInteger)y);
        break;
    case 3:
        cal = new Calculation_Mult((BigInteger)x, (BigInteger)y);
        break; 
    case 4 :
        cal = new Calculation_Div((BigInteger)x, (BigInteger)y);
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Wrong option");
}
result = (int) _0_DafnyCalculation_Compile.__default.calculate(new Calculation(cal));
Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

I have some questions based on the example:

1. Is there any way to call to function calculate(cal:Calculation) without having to construct a new Calculation object and including directly one "child-types" (Calculation_Sum, Calculation_Rest, etc.)?
2. Can _0_DafnyCalculation_Compile.__default. be avoided?
3. Is it necessary to import System.Numerics and use BigInteger to cast C# int and Dafny int? or can it be done in another way?

Thank you in advanced. I tried to be illustrative and clear, if any part is not understandable, do not hesitate to contact me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your questions.

1) Yes, there is now. Today, I checked in a change to the compiler which allows you to write

```
Calculation.create_Sum(A, B)
```

instead of the previous

```
new Calculation(new Calculation_Sum(A, B))
```

If your datatype has type parameters, they go immediately after the typename.

2) You can avoid mangled names like `_0_DafnyCalculation_Compile` by supplying your own via the `{:extern YourNameGoesHere}`, which can be placed on declarations like modules, classes, and methods. (If some declarations don't support `:extern` where you need it, please file that as a bug.)

(I've been working on some compiler changes lately. It's possible that I will be able to automatically remove the `_0_` prefix or the `_Compile` suffix in many cases. We'll see.)

3) If you use Dafny's type `int`, then you have to use `BigInteger` as you mentioned. But if you want to use native integer types, you can declare your own integer types in Dafny. For example,

```
newtype int32 = x | -0x8000_0000 <= x < 0x8000_0000
```

declares a Dafny type `int32` whose values are in the given range. (In this example, `x` is inferred to be of type `int`, but you can also specify the type explicitly, like `newtype int32 = x: int | ...`.) The Dafny compiler notices that this range fits in a signed 32-bit integer (written `int` in C#) and will therefore compile your Dafny type `int32` into C#'s `int`. This works for all the native .NET integer types.

If for some reason you want to use a larger native integer type than your range would allow, then you can indicate what you want with the `:nativeType` attribute.  For example,

```
newtype {:nativeType "short"} byteStoredUsing16Bits = x | -128 <= x < 128
```

will use a .NET `short` to store your `byteStoredUsing16Bits`type. Without the `:nativeType` attribute, the Dafny compiler would pick the .NET type `sbyte` for `byteStoredUsing16Bits`.

You can also use `{:nativeType false}` with `newtype` to say that you don't want the compiler to use a native integer (but instead use `BigInteger` as usual).

Note that the `newtype` declaration lets you define your own integer types, but that these are incompatible with Dafny's standard `int`. The main reason for using `newtype`, as opposed to declaring a subset type (by using the keyword `type` instead of `newtype`), is to allow the compiler to use a different representation. If you need to convert between various integer types, use the `as` operator. The following code snippet illustrates:

```
var x: int := 70;
var y: int32 := x as int32;
var z: byteStoredUsing16Bits := y as byteStoredUsing16Bits;
x := z as int;
```

Mathematically, he `as` operator is a partial identity function. That is, `as` never change a value, and the verifier will check that your conversion is from a value that exists in the destination type. (As an exercise, change the `70` in the example to `700` and watch the verifier complain.)

Also, note that all intermediate expressions of a `newtype` type must also adhere to whatever predicate you specify.

Rustan